# Create a universal helper variable

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Is there a way to create a variable at the top of template helpers to remove duplication.

In this particular situation I'm using  `var candidate = FlowRouter.getParam('id');` and I have to create the variable in each helper. I assume there is a better way.

```
professionalOverview: function() {
    var candidate = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
        return ProfessionalOverview.findOne({ candidateUserId: candidate });
    },
  candidateImg: function() {
    var candidateUserId = FlowRouter.getParam('id');

    return Files.findOne({ userId: candidateUserId });
  },
```

**EDIT**

```
Template.talentProfileNew.onCreated(function() {
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function(){
        this.candidateUserId = new ReactiveVar(FlowRouter.getParam('id'));
    }
});

Template.talentProfileNew.helpers({
  candidate: function() {
    console.log(Template.instance().candidateUserId.get());

    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Template.instance().candidateUserId.get()});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could read it once in onCreated() and put it in a reactive var. e.g.

```
Template.Foo.onCreated(function() {
    this.candidateUserId = new ReactiveVar(FlowRouter.getParam('id'));
});

Template.Foo.helpers({
    candidateImg() {
        return ProfessionalOverview.findOne({ userId: Template.instance().candidateUserId.get()});
    }
});
```

Comment: I get `Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: Inside your autorun, use self instead of this.